# How can I preinstall software on travis-ci?

Tags: docker, travis-ci

We use travis-ci for continuous integration. I'm troubled by the fact that our build process takes too long (~30 minutes). We depend on several Ubuntu packages which we fetch using apt-get, among others python-pandas.

We also have some of our own debs which we fetch over HTTPS and dpkg install. Finally, we have several pip/pypi requirements, such as Django, Flask, Werkzeug, numpy, pycrypto, selenium.

It would be nice to be able to at least pre-package some of these requirements. Does travis support something like this? How can I prepackage some of these requirements? Is it possible to build a custom travis base VM and start the build from there (perhaps using docker)? Especially the apt-get requirements from the default Ubuntu precise repository as well as the pip requirements should be easy to include.

Comment: I have no idea about travis, however, if you do not find a solution, maybe apt-get supports a local repository, that you can install on the machine where travis is installed, so as to cut some network time.

Comment: @watery travis is [provided as-a-service](https://travis-ci.org), and so we do not control the infrastructure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So while this question is already answered, it's doesn't actually provide a solution path. You can use cache directives in travis to cache your built packages for future travis runs.

```
cache:
  directories:
    - $HOME/.pip-cache/
    - $HOME/virtualenv/python2.7

install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt --download-cache "$HOME/.pip-cache"
```

Now your package content is saved for your next travis build. You can similarly store slow-to-retrieve resources in other directories and cache them.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. This seems to be available to private repositories, so we'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

Currently Travis-CI doesn't support such a feature. There are related issues currently open though such as [custom VMs](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1338), [running Docker in an OpenVz container](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1418) - (Spotify seems to have a somewhat working [example](https://github.com/spotify/helios/blob/master/.travis.sh) links in this issue), [using Linux Containers (LXC)](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1273), [using KVM](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/1419).

Some of those have workarounds mentioned in the issues, I'd give those a try until something more substantial is supported by Travis-CI. I'd also suggest reaching out to Travis-CI support and see if they have any suggestions (maybe there's something coming out soon that could help).